# Why setting Powershell to set-executionpolicy remotesigned fails?

Tags: powershell, security-policy

Using Win7-32bit and Powershell ISE I tried to run a just saved script (let's say containing a simple cls).
I got the error, that execution of scripts is forbidden with the usual "get-help about_signing" advice.

When using "set-executionpolicy remotesigned" to solve I got a dialogoue to verify whether I'm sure. But if I accept another error comes up:

```
acces to registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell" denied
    + set-executionpolicy <<<<  remotesigned
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAccessException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

What shall I do, to run saved scripts as user (or automatable as dayly service)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to run powershell as an administrator to set the execution policy.

Once you've set it to remotesigned, you can run powershell as a regular user.

Comment: I ran PowerShellISE as admin...

Comment: He means that you need to run in an elevated prompt.  You can right-click on the PowerShell icon in the task bar or start menu and select "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 7):

Just go to the controll panel -> administrative tools -> Windows PowerShell Modules (opens a powershell) and type the usual `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding the permissions directly to the windows registry.

Wrote about it here: [Powershell 101](http://kyleclegg.com/powershell/)

Hope this helps.