# PowerShell unable to Set-Execution policy

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set the script execution policy in PowerShell.

But when I tried, I get:

> PS C:\Users*> Get-ExecutionPolicy
>
> Restricted
>
> PS C:\Users*> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
>
> PS C:\Users*> Get-ExecutionPolicy
>
> Restricted

I tried to run in admin mode, but no difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why setting Powershell to set-executionpolicy remotesigned fails?](http://superuser.com/questions/158974/why-setting-powershell-to-set-executionpolicy-remotesigned-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you run PowerShell prompt as Administrator, or the proper access to the registry key `'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell'` will be denied.

Afterwhich, try setting it using`-force`, or `set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force`.

Comment: I ended up changing that registry by hand.